# Error: Restore through database

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have restored portal there is build in Microsoft Sharepoint Server 2010 through the "Sharepoint_Content" database. When I try to open portal, it brings the error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
0x80070012
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x80070012

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Have you any idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: what method you adopted to restore the site? is it content DB backup and restored? is it same web app or same farm? how many site collections in that content db

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the files of the site which was backed up are stored in database. But since the data in database was not restored the site does not work properly and hence the above error
As a workaround, you could restore it from content database directly. Here is an useful article for your reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx#section3

More reference:
http://spsite.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/backuprestore-sharepoint-content-database/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9f69cca-3d4c-4506-9743-a218fbc24fed/there-are-no-more-files-exception-from-hresult-0x80070012?forum=sharepointadminprevious